# Python-How do I write function to return True if a number (n) has two same digits in a row?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def double_eights(n):
    """Return true if n has two eights in a row
    >>> double_eights(8)
    False
    >>> double_eights(88)
    True
    >>> double_eights(2882)
    True
    >>> double_eights(880088)
    True
    >>> double_eights(12345)
    False
    >>> double_eights(80808080)
    False
    """
```

What will be my Code here?

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow isn't really meant for homework questions. If you really want to post one, please tell us what you tried, and what went wrong, so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be,

```
def double_eights(n):
    return '88' in str(n)
```

test cases

```
>>> double_eights(8) == False
True
>>> double_eights(88) == True
True
>>> double_eights(880088) == True
True
>>> double_eights(12345) == False
True
>>> double_eights(80808080) == False
True
```

Comment: @prashantrana the example 808 returns false, as the OP asked it will return true only for two eights in a row

Comment: @Oleg in question statement it is mention that any digit that  have occurenece more than or equal to 2 . cearly 8 is just example used by her

Comment: by __digits in row__ i understand a number follows itself